# En Python se usa pass, ¿qué puedo usar en Java?

Tags: java, try-catch

Estoy intentando un

```
try{//accion que a veces no se cumple
}
catch(error){//aquí necesito que haga algo igual que el pass de python
}
finally{//otra accion
}
```

En python era

```
try:una acción que no se cumple 

except:pass

finally:otra accion
```

Pero en Java, ¿cuál es el equivalente o cómo se hace?

Answer (score 2):

En java tienes que espeficar el tipo de exception en el catch:

```
try{ }
catch(Exception error){ }
finally{ }
```

Tambien puedes especificar mas de un catch para capturar las excepciones en base al tipo de la `Exception` lanzada:

```
try{ }
catch(NullPointerException nullException){ }
catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException invalidIndex){ }
catch(Exception error){ }
finally{ }
```

Esto lo que hará es que ejecutará el primer catch si dentro del `try` se produce un `NullPointerException` o el `catch` `IndexOutOfBoundsException` si intentas acceder a un índice inválido en un diccionario o colección, de lo contrario el último `catch` sera el que se ejecute.

Answer (score 2):

El `pass` en Python es una operación nula. Si quieres simular algo parecido imagino que lo más cercano es una función sin cuerpo:

```
private static void nada() {

}

try{
  // código
}
catch(error) {
  nada();
}
finally {
  // más código
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Primero que nada en Python, el try funciona de la siguiente forma:

```
try: 
    //  Bloque de código que se desea ejecutar, y puede generar alguna excepción.
except (RuntimeError, TypeError, NameError):
    //  En caso de que la acción en el bloque del try de una excepción 
    //  incluida en los parentesis del except, se ejecuta el bloque del except.
    //  La instrucción pass se utiliza para dar paso, 
    //  ya que en python no se deben dejar lineas vacías.
    pass  
finally:
    //  Acción que ejecutara SIEMPRE despues del bloque del TRY o si hubo una excepción,
    //  después del CATCH.
```

Mientras que en java funciona de igual forma excepto por el pass. En Java no es necesario usar la instrucción pass, simplemente dejas en blanco el catch del try:

```
try{
    //  Bloque de código que puede generar una excepción.
}catch(Excepcion e){
    //  En caso de que el try la genere, queda atrapada por el catch.
}finally{
    //  Bloque de código que se ejecutará siempre, ya sea
    //  después del TRY o del CATCH.
}
```

Espero esta explicación haya sido util en tu comparación del TRY en ambos lenguajes, saludos.